React and Vite whitescreen
Hi so I made this 3d portfolio and followed everything to deploy it to github pages. It works however I have an issue where my 3d models didnt load when i first click the link to the portfolio. My Navbar appears though, and its weird because if i click my about/projects/Contact everything is working well and i pressed back to my homepage at the HP icon, everything finally loads. I really dont know what to do to make it work.
This is the Home page When I first click the link to the portfolio
Here is the Home page when I click the the about page then the HP page]
I tried change the base in vite.config.js from base: '/Portfolio' to base: './' and even added a Loader to ensure that the model loads first.

  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
    const loadModel = async () => {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      setIsLoaded(true);
    };
    loadModel();`



I also saw that its because i didn't add import React from 'react' and added them to my model and pages .jsx files. But despite these changes there's still nothing
Heres a link to my portfolio: https://hchama.github.io/Portfolio/

nvm guys I fixed it. So what I noticed that when I deploy react + vite web app in github, if u get a white screen, its either because u didnt import react in ur pages or because the routing was not completed. In my case i used React router-dom, I didnt complete or set it up for deployment, so what I did to fix it was to add a basename in my  the basename should be the Repository and add another routing path "            <Route path="*" element={} />" This would make it direct to your home path. Hope this helps if anyone got the same issues as me!
